# Find the least positive value of alpha for the following trignometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Given question is : $$\sin(5\alpha + \theta) = \cos(\theta - 3\alpha)$$

We are to find the least **positive** value of $\alpha$ for which above equation holds.

The way I did is as, $$\sin5\alpha \cos\theta + \cos5\alpha \sin\theta = \cos\theta \cos3\alpha + \sin\theta \sin3\alpha$$

Now for this to be true $$\sin5\alpha = \cos3\alpha$$ and $$\cos5\alpha = \sin3\alpha$$

How do I find the value of $\alpha$ that satisfies the above criteria?

Comment: Your way is not correct. Your original equation doesn't imply $\sin 5\alpha=\cos 3\alpha$. That is just a particular case

Comment: Just to get the least value of $\alpha$ to satisfy the above equation, can't I just take this particular case and solve?

Comment: @Arnaldo The terminology is probably misleading: the aim seems to be finding $\alpha$ so that the relation $\sin(5\alpha+\theta)=\cos(\theta-3\alpha)$ holds for all $\theta$. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to ask for the minimum value of $\alpha$.

Comment: Actually, since $f(\theta) = \sin(5\alpha + \theta),$ also written $f(\theta) = cos(\theta - 3\alpha),$ belongs to the set of periodic functions of $\theta$ of period $2\pi,$ which set of functions is a vector space with basis $\sin\theta,$ $\cos\theta,$ it has a unique representation in the form $a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta$ for constants $a$ and $b.$ So once you have rewritten each of the formulas for $f$ in the form $a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta,$ the two coefficients of $\sin\theta$ must be equal and likewise the two coefficients of $\cos\theta.$ The two equations in the question follow.

Comment: @egreg: If your idea is correct then I agree but I don't think the equation must hold for all $\theta$. In fact, for a given $\theta$ you can find the proper $\alpha$

Comment: @AgentRock Isn't there some additional condition on $\alpha$? Perhaps it is required to be non-negative? For if the equation is true for $\alpha = \alpha_1,$ it is also true for $\alpha = \alpha_1-2\pi,$ hence there is no least value of $\alpha$ for which the equation holds.

Comment: @DavidK: I din't get your point. For a given $\theta$ then $\alpha=0$ is a solution?. Please see my answer and check if there is some problem.

Comment: @DavidK The question asked to find least positive value of $\alpha$. It is from the book by "Hugh Neil and Douglas Qualding" - Pure Mathematics 1. Chapter 18 (Radians) Exercise 18B, question 3.

Comment: @Arnaldo You raise an interesting point about interpretation. The question could have said, before giving the first equation, "For all $\theta$," or "For some $\theta$," or "For a given $\theta$." Each of these gives a different answer. So we have to decide which interpretation was intended by the question. (You chose "a given", but I initially thought you chose "some." The rest of us chose "all." Perhaps the exercise in the book is more explicit but this detail was left out of the question here, just as the detail that $\alpha$ is positive was left out.)

Comment: @DavidK No, see the main title. There i said, to find least positive value. And in the book, there is no special detail. You may check the book if you wish.

Comment: @DavidK> I agree. Probabily the OP is missing some important information given in the book.

Comment: @AgentRock: If your book didn't give you any further information then you got a question with a bad statement. As you can see in David's comment, you can get different answer with different interpretation.

Comment: @AgentRock The title is just a title, not part of the question itself. Don't expect people to go back and re-read the title in order to infer what the question body says. (They _might_ do so, but it's not reasonable to require that they _must_ do so.)

Comment: @Arnaldo Hmm, I see. The book is AS level(11th grade). So they probably asked for easier solution, like the one by egreg. But I liked the fact that there are actually two solutions, as you found out.

Comment: @DavidK Ok, will take note of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the two relations, after noting that none among $\sin5\alpha$, $\cos5\alpha$, $\sin3\alpha$ and $\cos3\alpha$ can be zero, if the relations you have are to hold. Then
$$
\tan5\alpha=\cot3\alpha=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-3\alpha\right)
$$
Recall that $\tan x=\tan y$ if and only if $x=y+k\pi$, for some integer $k$.

Comment: Super. Thank you so much! Got the answer, finally. And the correct answer was $\alpha = pi/16$

Comment: Your idea is right but the OP's idea to get those equations is wrong. So result that he will get from here is wrong.

Comment: @Arnaldo The OP found a couple of necessary conditions. The solutions of the equation in my answers are to be checked to actually give an identity.

Comment: The answer will fit because he got a particular case. But the equation has more solution. Please see the equation that I got.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be:

$$\sin(5\alpha + \theta) = \cos(\theta - 3\alpha)=\sin(\pi/2-\theta+3\alpha)$$

so, 
$$\sin(5\alpha + \theta) -\sin(\pi/2-\theta+3\alpha)=0$$

$$2\sin\left(\frac{(5\alpha + \theta)-(\pi/2-\theta+3\alpha)}{2}\right)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{(5\alpha + \theta)+(\pi/2-\theta+3\alpha)}{2}\right)=0$$

$$2\sin\left(\alpha + \theta-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cdot \cos\left(4\alpha+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$$

So your full solution is:

$$\cos\left(4\alpha+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0\to 4\alpha+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\to \alpha=\frac{\pi}{16}+\frac{k\pi}{4}$$
or

$$\sin\left(\alpha + \theta-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0\to \alpha + \theta-\frac{\pi}{4}=k\pi\to \alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta+k\pi$$

Comment: I got $\sin (\alpha + \theta - pi/4) cos(4\alpha + pi/4) = 0$. How do i go from here? Oh sorry, you had already done this. I think, earlier it  wasn't here.

Comment: @AgentRock: Just solve that equation and get your result. The result that you will get, from the chosen answer, will be incomplete once you got just a particular case.

Comment: For the least positive value, we take k = 0, and get $\alpha = pi/16$ from the first solution, which is the answer given in the book. Second solution is very interesting, in that it depends on $\theta$. Why do we not take it for positive value of $\alpha$?

Comment: @AgentRock: because your book was searching for the particular case as the egreg's answer.

Comment: but what does the other solution imply, can we have any $\theta$, subtract it from $\pi/4$, to fit in the equation? Will it work. Oh, i should try it.

Comment: Yeah, it works everytime. But a burning question, now I have is, how do I know that pi/16 is the minimum positive value that i needed. Why cannot it be say, pi/20 or lower than pi/16. Anyway to find this out?

Comment: @AgentRock: In a more general approach, we must have some more information about $\theta$. If we don't have it then is not possible to find the minimum.

Comment: When I took $\theta = 4pi/18$, i get $\alpha$ = pi/36, which is lower than pi/16. And i verified and this works. Looks like question itself is missing important details.

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is crystal clear now. This will help lot of future students. Wow. Thank you.

Comment: @AgentRock: you are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

use then $$\sin(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$